# Simple Posterior probability problem but confusing to me

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, posterior

In a factory, there are many machines which packaging many type of products. Due to technical problem, all of them damage the product A during the process except three machines with fewer damaged products. Here is the detail table:

Machine number -----probability getting Product A -----% cause damage on Product A

```
      1  ---------------25% --------------95%
      2 ----------------30%---------------98%
      3 ----------------34% --------------97%
```

If you received an non-damaged product A, what is the probability that this product come from machine number 3?

I have no idea where to start, please help.
Thanks

Comment: This sounds like an exercise question - see http://stats.stackexchange,com/tags/self-study/info.   However, I don't understand the problem - what are "probability getting Product A" and "% cause damage on Product A"?

Comment: I believe your information may be incomplete: there must be more machines involved, because the chances that they package product A sum only to 89% rather than 100%.

Comment: @whuber, he did mention (as far as I can tell) that all other machines are guaranteed to damage product A, so we do have complete information. $P(damage \mid other) = 1$ and $P(other) = 0.11$.

Comment: @whuber, it is exactly what Bridgeburner said

Comment: Thank you both (@Bridgeburners) for clearing that up!  I hope these observations have given you a place to start.  If not, could you at least tackle a simpler version of this problem?  For instance, suppose machine 1 receives 25% of product A and machine 2 receives the remaining 75%.  How would you proceed?

Comment: Supposed the question is about undamaged product in machine 2 then it asks about finding P(M2,undamaged). The numerator is [P(undamaged,M2)*P(M2)] and denominator is [P(undamaged,M1)*P(M1) + P(undamaged,M2)*P(M2) or P(undamaged), from data we have P(undamaged,M1) = 0.05, P(M1) = 0.25 and P(undamaged,M2)= 0.02, P(M2) = 0.75. Plug those number into numerator and denominator and we have the result, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start by taking the proportion of each machine's undamaged product $A$s as our best estimate for the probability of not damaging the product, given said machine. That is, we can take,
$$
\begin{split}
P(undamaged \mid M1) &= 0.05 \\
P(undamaged \mid M2) &= 0.02 \\
P(undamaged \mid M3) &= 0.03 \\
P(undamaged \mid other) &= 0 
\end{split}
$$
where $other$ refers to any other machine. Keep in mind that we're taking a Frequentist estimate here; because that was the proportion of undamaged product $A$s we observed from those machines thus far, we are using that as our estimate for the probability. If we wanted to get more sophisticated here (which we should if our sample was small when obtaining those figures) we should assign priors to those probability values and come up with a distribution for those estimates, but let's use these static estimates for now.

We also know, as far as I can tell from your wording, that given that a product $A$ comes into the production line, the probabilities that it's distributed to any of the machines is (from your table),

$$
\begin{split}
P(M1) &= 0.25 \\
P(M2) &= 0.3 \\
P(M3) &= 0.34 \\
P(other) &= 0.11.
\end{split}
$$

Now, keep in mind the sum and product rules of probability, 
$$
\begin{split}
P(a) &= \sum_b P(a,b) \\
P(a,b) &= P(a \mid b) P(b),
\end{split}
$$
where $b$ is an event that happens in tandem with $a$ and the sum is over all possible mutually exclusive and collectively exhaustive values of $b$ that can occur with $a$. In your case, you want $P(undamaged)$, so in analogy to the generic labels I gave to the arguments of the sum and product rules, assign $undamaged$ to $a$, and assign $M1$, $M2$, $M3$, and $other$ to the possible values of $b$.

Finally, keep in mind that the decomposition of the product rule can go in either direction. That is, $$P(a \mid b) P(b) = P(a,b) = P(b \mid a) P(a).$$ In your case, you can write this as $$P(undamaged \mid M3) P(M3) = P(undamaged,M3) = P(M3 \mid undamaged) P(undamaged).$$ Notice that this is just a rearranged form of Bayes' theorem.

With the above, you have enough information to find the thing you're looking for, which is $P(M3 \mid undamaged)$.

Comment: Thank you, just want to be clear, is P(undamaged) = P(undamaged, M1) + P(undamaged, M2) + P(undamaged, M3)? Because I find another similar question from another place but when I apply. The result does not match the answer.

Comment: Yes, it happens to be true in this case. In general, though you want to sum over *all* undamaged possibilities, including $P(undamaged, other)$. It just so happens, in this case, that $P(undamaged, other) = 0 $.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong, it should be  P(undamaged) = P(undamaged, M1)P(M1) + P(undamaged, M2)P(M2)  + P(undamaged, M3)P(M3). Now I understand everything, thanks a lot

Comment: Actually, you were right the first time. You're mixing up $P(undamaged, M2)$ with $P(undamaged \mid M2)$ which are different. $P(undamaged, M2) = P(undamaged \mid M2) P(M2).$ The former is the *joint* distribution (probability that they're both true at the same time) and the latter is the *conditional* distribution (probability of undamaged *given* M2).